# Ansible yum module does not see repositories with option installroot

Tags: ansible, yum

I would like to install the base CentOS to a specify directory, example to /var/centos. The directory is empty. I usage the next command in yum:

```
yum --disablerepo='*' --enablerepo='base,updates' --releasever=7 --installroot=/var/centos groupinstall @core
```

This command installs the base system without any problems. I want to do the same through Ansible.

In Ansible I usage the next task:

```
    - name: Install base CentOS
      yum:
        state: latest
        name: "@core"
        installroot: "/var/centos/"
        disablerepo: "*"
        enablerepo: "base,updates"
        releasever: "7"
```

When executing a playbook I receive an error:

```
Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: base/$releasever/x86_64
```

As I understand, the yum don't see any repo.

I make list:

```
    - name: Install base CentOS
      yum:
        list: repos
        installroot: "/var/centos/"
```

When I execute the task I receive nothing.

Why doesn't yum module see repos?

**Updated.**
Before performing the Install base task, I executed the command - `rpm --root /var/centos --force --nodeps -ivh http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/centos-release-7-6.1810.2.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm`, after that everything worked.

The final playbook:

```
  vars:
    root_path: "/var/centos/"
  tasks:
    - name: Install package centos-release-7-6.1810.2.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm
      shell: rpm --root {{ root_path }} --force --nodeps -ivh http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/centos-release-7-6.1810.2.el7.centos.x86_64.rpm

    - name: Install base CentOS
      yum:
        state: installed
        name:
          - "@core"
        installroot: "{{ root_path }}"
        disablerepo: "*"
        enablerepo: "base,updates"
        releasever: "7"
```

Comment: I have the same issue when trying to automatize my offline yum repository. I am just using _command_ so far, don's see any other way.